# Unable to put a bounty of only 50 on my question

Tags: support, bounty

I wanted to put a bounty on an [old question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46233/converting-djvu-to-pdf), but am only able to put up 100, 150, 200, 250 or 300 (no option of 50). Any ideas why?

[FAQs](http://FAQs%20says%20I%20should%20be%20able%20to%20do%20just%2050.) says I should be able to do just 50. Is this something to do with an answer already being accepted? *I want to advertise for a better answer* :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of the system.

It assumes that you haven't had much success with the bounty, so it automatically ups it to double what it was last time (or something along those lines).

However, if you explain what you want to bounty it as, someone in the community (*cough* me *cough*) will bounty it for you at 50 rep.

Comment: (oh, and ask nicely. ;))

Comment: aaah, I didn't realise I had already put a bounty on it in the past! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: (I wanted to put a bounty on it to see if anyone knew of/if there existed a new solution which could recover the pictures):)

Comment: @haydoni You might want to unmark it as answered, then put your partial solution in your question and reword it so it's obvious that you need the pictures recovered. Comment here when you've done that, I'd be happy to bounty it for you.

Comment: @Jorge I have reworded and unmarked it as answered (I think it makes it clear?), if you could bounty it that would be **heroic**!